# Can Popcorn.js be used to add subtitles to a YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, popcornjs

Let's say we embed a YouTube video on a web page.

Underneath the video player, could we display subtitles synched to the video using a media framework like [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose the HTML5 version when embedding the YouTube video and if it's actually being played within an HTML5 browser, it's just a `video` tag so you can use Popcorn.js. When it's a Flash, I'm not sure if you can get into that Flash and know the progress and listen to the events.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting you mentioned Popcorn.js, because Popcorn does support Youtube.

http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-with-youtube

Buuut, that documentation is out of date.

It is now:

"var example = Popcorn.youtube("

There are new docs on their way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [YouTube JavaScript Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_status), you can use `player.getCurrentTime()` to find out which line of subtitling to show.

Then again, YouTube already supports subtitles to begin with.